# Django CSRF not working on SSL(HTTPS), but working on local(linux), tried all things

Tags: django, django-forms, csrf, django-csrf

Following is the error I get:

`403: CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.`

When `Debug = True`, reason given for failure is:

```
Origin checking failed - https://example.com does not match any trusted origins.
```

Basic checks:

1. Site is having valid working SSL
2. Browser is accepting cookie for this site
3. In `settings.py` `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True` is set
4. In `settings.py` `"django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware"` is above other view middleware

I have tried many things, nothing works. It works perfectly on development environment

Comment: Did not understand your question ? It is not mentioned anywhere though about samesite cookie issue.

Comment: Does it literally say "example.com" or did you edit your real domain here for privacy reasons?

Comment: Do you have [`CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS) set? Do you have [`ALLOWED_HOSTS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) set? Does any of them include `example.com` (without `www.` if you don't use it)?

Comment: CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["https://example.com"] added, now it's giving 500 error, I will try to solve this one now. ngnix and gunicorn logs gave no error(i checked from journal ctl commands)